# How to get multiple rows/columns matched from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a records table and a history table that adds timestamps as records flow through our system. They look something like this...

```
records
+------+-----------+----+
|   id | name      | ...|
+------+-----------+----+
|    1 | host1     | ...|
|    2 | host2     | ...|
|    3 | host3     | ...|
|    4 | host4     | ...|
+------+-----------+----+

history
+----+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
| id | record_id | timestamp  | module | status |
+----+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
|  5 | 1         | 2019-01-01 | eng    | new    |
|  6 | 1         | 2019-01-03 | eng    | done   |
|  7 | 2         | 2019-01-01 | eng    | new    |
|  8 | 2         | 2019-01-04 | eng    | done   |
|  9 | 3         | 2019-01-02 | eng    | new    |
+----+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
```

This is greatly simplified as the history table may or may not contain many different modules and status entries depending on record workflow. What I need is a list of records along with a timestamp for NEW and DONE if they exist or null if not, like this...

```
+------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
|   id | name      | eng_start_time |  eng_end_time |
+------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
|    1 | host1     | 2019-01-01     | 2019-01-03    |
|    2 | host2     | 2019-01-01     | 2019-01-04    |
|    3 | host3     | 2019-01-02     | null          |
|    4 | host4     | null           | null          |
+------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
```

I was able to get these results by using 2 subqueries, but I fear this might not be efficient as these tables grow very large. Here's my query that works. Is there a way to get these results with a more efficient join/subselect?

```
select r.id, r.name, 
  (select timestamp from history where request_id = r.id and module="eng" and status="new") as eng_start_time,
  (select timestamp from history where request_id = r.id and module="eng" and status="done") as eng_end_time
  from records r order by r.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with two left `JOIN`s.

```
select r.id, r.name, h_start.timestamp eng_start_time, h_end.timestamp eng_end_time
from records r
left join history h_start 
    ON h_start.request_id = r.id AND h_start.module='eng' AND h_start.status='new'
left join history h_end
    ON h_end.request_id = r.id AND h_end.module='eng' AND h_end.status='done'
order by r.id
```

NB : I replaced your double quotes with singles, that is a better practice in SQL.

Comment: Aha! I was very close to this, but was adding the where conditions in the where clause instead of in the JOIN. That was the key to making this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need some LEFT JOINs:

```
select r.id, r.name, hs.timestamp as eng_start_time, he.timestamp as eng_end_time
  from records r
  left join history hs on r.id = hs.request_id and hs.module="eng" and hs.status="new"
  left join history he on r.id = he.request_id and he.module="eng" and he.status="done"
  order by r.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer! I only upvoted the other because he gave the same answer first :)